# Select All Option in Bootstrap MultiSelect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I m using below code for Bootstrap Multiselect, and i want to include "selectAll" option in the multiselect.

```
  <div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px">@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Id, Model.SelectIdList, new { @id = "lstIds" })</div>
```

Javascript Code:-

```
  $('#lstIds').multiselect({
        buttonWidth: '200px',
        enableFiltering: true,
        includeSelectAllOption: true
    });
```

Here when i add includeSelectAllOption to true then Multiselect will become as Listbox, not sure why , any one suggest me what might be the issues.